# Problemas con $AJAX (jquery) y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hola estoy queriendo guardar un registro por ajax y que no me recargue la pagina, me esta volviendo loco AJAX no lo puedo hacer funcionar, sale por success pero no me guarda el registro.
las variables que pasa por post, las carga bien, ya que hice un alert y va bien... y sale por el success pero no veo el error y en consola no arroja ningun error....a ver si me pueden ayudar, se los agradezco

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form_historial" name="form_historial">
    <input type="number" id="codigo_cliente" class="codigo_cliente" value="<?= $codigo ?>">
    <label for="titulo" id="titulo" class="form-control alert-success">Cargar nueva 
                 informacion del Cliente </label>
    <label for="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control">Fecha: </label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control datos_clientes fecha" required>
    <div id="con-editor">
        <div id="editor">
            <div id="cajaTexto" contenteditable>

            </div>
            <div id="menu_barra">
                <button type="button" data-type="bold" class="comando" id="btnBold"><b>B</b> 
                 </button>
                <button type="button" data-type="italic" class="comando" id="btnItalic"><i>i</i> 
                 </button>
                <button type="button" data-type="underline" class="comando" id="btnUnderline"> 
                 <span>S</span></button>
                <button type="button" data-type="foreColor" class="comando" id="btnColor"><span>A</span> 
                 </button>
                <button type="button" data-type="backColor" class="comando" id="btnBackColor"> 
                 <span>A</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="guardar_historial" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Ese es el codigo que tengo cargado en HTML, saco el valor del Input number, el valor de input date y el valor que cargo en el cajaTexto y los capturo con Jquery con el siguiente codigo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#guardar_historial').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var codigo = $('#codigo_cliente').val();
        var detalle = $('#cajaTexto').text();
        var fecha = $('.fecha').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'procesar_historial.php',
            data: {
                codigo: codigo,
                descripcion: detalle,
                fecha: fecha
            },

            success: function(r) {
                if (r === 1) {
                    alert("agregado con exito");
                } else {
                    alert("fallo el server");
                }

            },

            error: function() {
                alert("Error no se puede guardar el registro");
            }


        })

    })
})
```

parece enviarlo pero no puedo verificarlo en el archivo php, le hago un var_dump a $_POST pero no me imprime nada...el codigo de procesar_historial.php es.

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

$codigo="";
$fecha="";
$descripcion="";

echo($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['fecha']) {

    require 'validar_cliente.php';

    ini_set('display_errors','off');

    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE_NAME);

    if (!$link) {
        header ('Location: ' . NOMBRE_ARCHIVO_ERRORES);
        die;
    }

        mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_DATABASE_CHARSET);

        $codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $codigo);
        $descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $descripcion);
        $fecha = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $fecha);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO detalle_cliente ( id_clientes, detalle, fecha ) VALUES
                ($codigo, '$descripcion', $fecha)";

        $rs = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        mysqli_close($link);
        
        echo ($rs);
    
    } else {

        $r=0;
        echo($r);
        var_dump($POST);
    }

?>
```

eso es todo, gracias!

Comment: Usa `var_dump($_POST)`  en vez de `echo($_POST)` para ver que esta recibiendo.

Comment: no imprime nada ni con echo ni con var_dump!!!

Comment: ¿Ya corroboraste que AJAX realmente esté enviando datos?, puedes verificarlo añadiendo `beforeSend: alert({codigo: codigo, descripcion: detalle, fecha: fecha}),` después de `url`. Saludos.

Comment: mira Josue cuando hago lo que me decis, en el alert dice [object Object] sin mostrar valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Primer error:

No cierras la el primer `if` del código php:

```
if (isset($_POST['fecha']) {
```

#### Segundo error:

Usa `var_dump($_POST);` en vez de `echo($_POST);`

#### Prueba para determinar el problema:

Añade en `success: function(r)` la siguiente línea:

```
success: function(r) {
    console.log(r); // Esta línea
    if (r === 1) {
        alert("agregado con exito");
    } else {
        alert("fallo el server");
    }
},
```

> Si después de corregir el primer error sigues teniendo problemas,
> comenta lo que muestra el console.log(r);

Comment: si Brahim tenias razon, el problema era que no habia cerrado el if, ahi me funcionó.....gracias gracias

Comment: Perfecto, de nada!. Puedes marcar la respuesta como válida si así es.

Comment: no se como hacerlo, soy nuevo!